# Google Maps DOS attack

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

We're using Google's Geocoding service on our website to allow users to enter a zip code and find nearby locations. We've recently been having a problem with exceeding the request limit of 25,000 per day (for 90 consecutive days). We shouldn't be getting this much traffic and I've just found, when enabling logging, that we got 133 requests in about 35 minutes. That seems like way to much. I'm suspecting some kind of scripted attack. What can I do to verify & prevent it?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be over 25K... 133*22 < 25K.

Comment: Lets say you maintain an average 133 requests every 35 minutes. That's aproxx. 6000 hits, give or take couple hundred. That's no where near the 25k your claiming. Keep watching logs, and find out when you get the hits.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P - 25k Google's claiming* The point was 133 is more than I was expecting in that period and more importantly that we're being blocked by Google. Maybe our expectations are too low on the 133, but the max unique visitors we've had in a day was 12K. It's not likely we hit that for 90 consecutive days and every one of those days they each did 2 locations searches. It's possible, just unlikely. Should I log unique IP addresses?

Comment: Maybe you need to limit your allowed request per ip per hour - or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reading through the API docs again and finding that it should've been coded so that the geocoding request occurs on the client-side. So I updated our pages to use client script to make the geocoding request. That way if a user wants to abuse it, they get blocked, not my server. The client script then sends my page the lat and long coordinates that it needed and it goes from there without having to interface with Google on the server side.